# JQuery Animate function stopping on second index in array

Tags: jquery, animation

I pulled some code from an old project I used and was trying to replicate it on a new one. It uses jQuery to animate (Fade in/Fade out) text in a H2.

And I am putting in a `<span id="services"></span>`. It iterates until the second item in the array (index 1) and then stops. Any ideas why?

```js
var array = ["Marketing", "Web Design", "Hosting", "Search Engine Optimization", "Business"];
var index = 0;
$("#services").text(array[0]);

(function animate() {
  $("#services").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    index = (index + 1) % array.length;
    this.textContent = array[index];
  }).fadeIn(1000, animate);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js""></script>

<span id="services"></span>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Works for me in jQuery 3.6.1 - perhaps you load more than one jQuery library?

Comment: I have 3.7 installed right now. I always get this error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fadeIn')```

Comment: Nope. Works too with 3.7 - I updated the snippet.

Comment: ok, so then I must have a reference problem somewhere in my code I would think. That is the only area that jquery is used on that page to animate anything. Any other suggestions why it wouldn't work?

Comment: If something removes or replaces $("#services") or gives the ID to another element perhaps? Do you ajax stuff in?

Comment: No, MEAN stack, and its on a landing page with nothing else modified. I am checking to make sure I don't have that id used anywhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253716/discussion-between-andrew-buccellato-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a conflict with a UI that I was using that had the same name for a javascript function. Thank you to those who helped me identify that issue.